# Email regex not allowing null value

Tags: regex, angular

I'm using Angular and using this validator

```
public static validate(c: AbstractControl) {
const EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(|(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/i;

return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : {
  validateEmail: {
    valid: false
  }
};
```

}

It does not allow me to have an empty value in input field.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, it does: https://regex101.com/r/SdK1EG/1

Comment: is the return null, a truthy value for validate ? `EMAIL_REGEXP.test('')` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have specific requirements, you can simply use the e-mail validator that Angular provides.

```
mailControl: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.email]);
```

If you don't add a required validator, you will have the option to let it empty.

Comment: may it because of my html part of code?
<input formControlName="email" id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="formControls['email'].errors && submitted" class="alert alert-danger">
 <div *ngIf="formControls['email'].errors.validateEmail">incorrect email format</div>
</div>

Comment: Look, I'm no wizard, I can't guess your error. You only provided your custom validator. Angular provides both required and email validator, you should use them. You have their documentation for the implementation.